# knockout binding doesn't seem to bind :)

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I have the multiple divs on a page which are marked with a specific class. something like :

```
<div class="modal-body auctionRequested" >  

    <table data-bind="foreach: auctionBatches">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: $data.Id"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: $data.Name"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>  
<div class="modal-footer">  
<a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Call to action</a>  
<a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>  
</div>  
</div>  
</div>
```

the viewmodel is defined as following :

```
function AuctionBatch(id, name, logoUrl, startDate, endDate, isBlind, isBuyNow) {
        this.id = ko.observable(id);
        this.name = ko.observable(name);
        this.logoUrl = ko.observable(logoUrl);
        this.startDate = ko.observable(startDate);
        this.endDate = ko.observable(endDate);
    }

    function AuctionBatchList() {
        this.auctionBatches = ko.observableArray([]);

    }
```

and it is applied in the following manner:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
        var auctions = [];
        $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("GetAuctionBatches", "CarStates")',
                type: 'GET',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    success: function (data) {
                    if (data.success) {
                        auctions= data.list;  

                        modals = $('.auctionRequested');
                        $.each(modals, function(i, item) {
                        var vm = ko.dataFor(item);
                        vm.auctionBatches(auctions);

                        });

                     } 
                    else {
                        $("#error").css("display", "block");
                        $("#errorText").text(data.message);
                    }
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("error");
                }
            });

        var modals = $('.auctionRequested');
                   $.each(modals, function(i, item) {
                        ko.applyBindings(new AuctionBatchList(), item);   
                   });
});
```

However although I can see in firebug that there are multiple elements retrieved from the server, nothing is bound on the ui and I also can see no error. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

You're using the wrong names:

try this:

```
<td data-bind="text:id">
<td data-bind="text:name">
```

(You don't need $data in front and you used capital letters)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is with code you're not showing, or with the data that's being returned. Perhaps I can best help you by supplying a working example of the code you posted, see [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Hhd8c/1/), where I've done two things:

- Moved the `applyBindings` bit above the Ajax call. Because of the way your `success` function is working you'll need to be absolutely sure things are bound in time.
- Mocked the Ajax calls like this:

  ```
  // Mock $.ajax calls:
  $.ajax = function(options) {
      options.success({ 
          success: true,
          list :  [
              {Id: 1, Name: 'Test A'},
              {Id: 1, Name: 'Test B'}
          ]
      });
  };
  ```

With those changes the code you posted seems to be functioning.

A few notes though about the code:

- You have an `AuctionBatch` constructor function but it's not being used anywhere.
- If you save a reference to the `new AuctionBatchList` in the correct scope you won't need to use jQuery to find it again in the `success` function. Typically with KO, if you feel you need a `$('some-selector')` call there will also be a solution less tightly coupled to a specific View. Here's an [updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Hhd8c/2/) with an example of that.
- Your View code has a closing `</div>` with no matching opening `<div>`.

Hope this helps!